# Reuse Director for new scene

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x

I am currently working on an Cocos2d-x, which uses native UI (UIKit Framework) besides the Game.

This is my actual workflow:

When I start the game every things works well. I can even restart the game by reinitializing the scene, but I can't pop the UIViewController with my CCEAGLView and push it again on the top.

When I do this I get a scene without any movement. 
Here's my opens the scene:

```
    if (cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->getRunningScene() && [[self.view.subviews firstObject] isKindOfClass:[CCEAGLView class]]) {

    //Restart scene without popping ViewController
    //Works well
    auto beam = GrowingBeam::createLayer();
    auto scene = beam->getScene();
    beam->_self  = (__bridge void*) self;
    cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->replaceScene(scene);
}else {


    if (cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->getRunningScene()) {

        //Restart scene after View Controller has been popped
        // DOESN'T WORK !!
        auto beam = GrowingBeam::createLayer();
        auto scene = beam->getScene();

        beam->_self  = (__bridge void*) self;

        [self.view insertSubview:(__bridge CCEAGLView *) cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->getOpenGLView()->getEAGLView() atIndex:0];
        cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->replaceScene(scene);
        scene->resume();
        cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->resume();
    }else {

        //Start Scene for the first time
        //Works well
        CCEAGLView *eaglView = [CCEAGLView viewWithFrame: [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds
                                             pixelFormat: kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                             depthFormat: GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES
                                      preserveBackbuffer: NO
                                              sharegroup: nil
                                           multiSampling: NO
                                         numberOfSamples: 0];

        // IMPORTANT: Setting the GLView should be done after creating the RootViewController
        auto gl2view = cocos2d::GLView::createWithEAGLView((__bridge void*)eaglView);
        cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->setOpenGLView(gl2view);

        [self.view insertSubview:eaglView atIndex:0];

        auto beam = GrowingBeam::createLayer();
        auto scene = beam->getScene();
        beam->_self  = (__bridge void*) self;

        cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->runWithScene(scene);
        cocos2d::Application::getInstance()->run();

    }

}
```

Comment: I do something similar, but they the check for `if (cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->getRunningScene())`. Also interesting that you are apparently creating a layer in `GrowingBeam` that has a scene object that you do after. I haven't seen it done quite that way before. usually people do it the other way around.

Comment: Acutaully I have to access the Layer to pass some data to it. Thats why I'm doing it the other way around.